# NgCordova vs Pure Cordova , what should i choose ?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am building hybrid mobile application using Ionic framework-v1 , 
and i am worried about what plugins should i use .. ngCordova plugins or pure Cordova  plugins  and why , and what're the cons and pros  of each option ??

and to let you know  i faced some problems in ngCordova plugins that's why im asking  .

Thank You .

Comment: any specific reason you are using Ionic framework-v1  and not ionic3

Comment: I fear this is a [primarily opinion-based question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Yes ,  I  started working on the project   before ionic 3 released .